How to add an else statement in powershell script to list Running VMs showing as Not Ready
I am using a Powershell script that lists VMs that are Running and have an Agent Status as Not Ready.
At the moment, if all VMs are ready, then the output is empty. I want to add a else statement to include that if VMs Agent Status is "Ready" then print "All VMs are Ready".
Here is the script:
Set-AzContext -Subscription "MySub"
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$output = @()
$VMs_running = Get-AzVM  -status | ?{$_.PowerState -eq 'VM running'}


foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
    $VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status
    
    $Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
    $Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
    $Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
    $Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
    $Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
    if ($Row.VMAgent_Status -ne "Ready"){
      $output += $Row
    }
}

$output


exact replica of your previous question. provide feedback there instead of re-asking the same again

I did indeed sir. :)

You want a different If/Else statement at the end. Replace the last line with something like:
If($output){$output}else{"All VMs are Ready"}

